# Use asterisk * instead of year in object with dates?

Tags: javascript, date

I have this code to calculate days between dates and skip holidays.

```
var gon = {};
gon["holiday"] = "2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-10-31".split(",");

// 2 helper functions - moment.js is 35K minified so overkill in my opinion
function pad(num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); }
function formatDate(date) { var d = new Date(date), dArr = [d.getFullYear(), pad(d.getMonth() + 1), pad(d.getDate())];return dArr.join('-');}

function calculateDays(first,last) {
  var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  daysDiff = parseInt((last.getTime()-first.getTime())/aDay,10);

  if (daysDiff>0) {
    for (var i = first.getTime(), lst = last.getTime(); i <= lst; i += aDay) {
      var d = new Date(i);
      console.log(d.getDay());
      if (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0 // weekend
      || gon.holiday.indexOf(formatDate(d)) != -1) {
          daysDiff--;
      }
    }
  }
  return daysDiff;
}
```

How can I use asterisk * instead of year to cover all years. I don't want to do like this

```
gon["holiday"] = "2018-08-28,2018-09-25,2019-08-28,2019-09-25,2020-08-28,2020-09-25,2021-08-28,2021-09-25".split(",");
```

Can I do something like this

```
gon["holiday"] = "*-08-28,*-09-25".split(",");
```

Comment: Sure you can. In your loop you also need to keep the current year. Then replace the asterisk with the current year.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose though? Sometimes holidays fall on a different day depending on the year. How would you determine which day was the relevant one without the year available?

Comment: This dates is always the same, ex Christmas day.

Answer (score 0):

This code could do the work for you:

```
gon["holiday"]= [...Array(10)].map((_,i) => (2015+i) + "-08-28");
```

Results:

```
(10) ["2015-08-28", "2016-08-28", "2017-08-28", "2018-08-28", "2019-08-28", "2020-08-28", "2021-08-28", "2022-08-28", "2023-08-28", "2024-08-28"]
```

Comment: This is a nice way of creating 10 annual dates, but I am not sure that it will solve the problem, as none of the dates actually repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findIndex and provide it a function that would only match the day and month instead of the year, like so:

```
var gon = {};
gon["holiday"] = "*-08-28,*-09-25".split(",");

function pad(num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); }
function formatDate(date) { var d = new Date(date), dArr = [d.getFullYear(), pad(d.getMonth() + 1), pad(d.getDate())];return dArr.join('-');}

function calculateDays(first,last) {
  var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  daysDiff = parseInt((last.getTime()-first.getTime())/aDay,10);

  if (daysDiff>0) {
    for (var i = first.getTime(), lst = last.getTime(); i <= lst; i += aDay) {
      var d = new Date(i);
      console.log(d.getDay());
      if (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0 // weekend
      || gon.holiday.findIndex((h)=>formatDate(d).replace(/[^-]+-/, '') == h.replace(/[^-]+-/, '')) != -1) {
          daysDiff--;
      }
    }
  }
  return daysDiff;
}
```

I'm using a regular expression to remove the year, it removes the first occurrence of a dash and any characters before it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array for holidays with fixed anniversaries in MM-DD format:

```
var fixedHols = ['08-28','09-25'];
```

another for those that move more or less randomly, such as easter, ramadan, diwali:

```
var movingHols = ['YYYY-MM-DD',...]
```

and another for rules–based holidays that is generated for the given year like the first Monday in May or the Tuesday following the first Monday in November or whatever, then test dates against them, e.g.

```js
function isHoliday(date) {
  let z = n => (n<10?'0':'')+n;
  let fixedHols = ['08-28','09-25'];
  let ymd = formatDate(date);
  let md  = ymd.slice(-5);
  let movingHols = [ /* dates as YYY-MM-DD */ ];
  let rulesHols  = [ /* generate YYY-MM-DD for date.getFullYear() */ ];

  // If date is in any array return true, otherwise return false
  return [fixedHols, movingHols, rulesHols].some((hols, i) => hols.includes(i? ymd : md));
}

function formatDate(d) {
  var z = n => (n<10?'0':'')+n;
  return d.getFullYear()+'-'+z(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+z(d.getDate());
}

[new Date(2018,7,27), // 27 Aug
 new Date(2018,7,28), // 28 Aug
 new Date(2018,7,29), // 29 Aug
 new Date(2021,7,28), // 28 Aug
 new Date(2018,8,25), // 25 Sep
 new Date(2018,8,26)] // 26 Sep
   .forEach(d => 
   console.log(`Is ${formatDate(d)} a holiday? ${isHoliday(d)?'Yes':'No'}`)
);
```